# Fluids in a U-shaped Tube

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

One of the users asked a [question about the Fluids in U-shaped Tube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160542/fluids-in-u-shaped-tube). I was wondering and I tried to imagine that the membrane is fixed and the left side is filled up until $h_1=h_2$. So my question is what happens when the membrane is made movable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is free to move, then there is no external force keep it in place and pressures must balance. If it is fixed a reaction force $F$ is needed which imposes different pressures on each side.

[image: pic]

So the balance of forces on the membrane is $\frac{F}{A}+\rho_1 g h_1  = \rho_2 g h_2 $. Now if $h_1=h_2$ there is no need the reaction force and if the membrane is let free it is going to stay put as the sum of forces is already zero.

Comment: Being pedantic, strictly that is balance of pressure, not force. And aren't the densities different $(\rho_1 \ne \rho_2)$? The original question says water and oil.

Comment: It is the balance of forces that creates an equilibrium. I will update the answer with differing densities.

Comment: Your equation shows a balance of pressure, not force.

Comment: I know I shouldn't have being answering with my eyes closed! Actually it is a force balance divided by area, so it appears like a pressure balance.

Comment: It happens. I've done worse.